# How to plot vertical lines at specific dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

How could I add a vertical line marker to this chart at a specific date? `Week end` is the date column.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,9))
thirteen.plot.line(x='Week end', y='OFF', color='crimson', ax=ax)
thirteen.plot.line(x='Week end', y='ON', color='blue', ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: image of output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure the date column `Week end` has been converted [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Then use either [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) or [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html):

- [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) can only plot one vertical line at a time and will automatically fill the whole `y` range
- [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html) can plot multiple vertical lines at once, but you have to specify the `y` bounds

```
# convert to datetime date type
thirteen['Week end'] = pd.to_datetime(thirteen['Week end'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 9))
thirteen.plot.line(x='Week end', y='OFF', color='crimson', ax=ax)
thirteen.plot.line(x='Week end', y='ON', color='blue', ax=ax)

# plot vertical line at one date
ax.axvline(x='2013-07-01', color='k')

# plot vertical lines at two dates from y=0 to y=250
ax.vlines(x=['2013-11-01', '2014-04-15'], ymin=0, ymax=250, color='k', ls='--')
```

[image: output]